# Javascript - Match (and replace) value to array of array

Tags: javascript, replace, match

After parsing values through Ajax request (GET), I need to replace them with other values -> i.e. multiple postal codes corresponding to the same country code ( "1991,1282,6456" : "Idaho", etc.  )

This is what I've done so far :

```js
$mapCodes = {
  '1991': 'Idaho',
  '1282': 'Idaho',
  '5555': 'Kentucky',
  '7777': 'Kentucky '
}
var region = value.groupid.replace(/7777|5555|1282|1991/, function(matched) {
  return $mapCodes[matched];
});
console.log(region);
```

This works, but I'd rather avoid setting my $mapCodes variable as a long list of values repeated.

I need something like and array of array to whitch make the match (and then the replacement)

```
$mapCodes = {
'1991,1282' : 'Idaho',
'7777,5555' : 'Kentycky'
}
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made to reflect the actual code you have  - there is not `value.groupid` defined. I also added a quote and a comma to the invalid object

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? Is the issue that you want to write non-repetitive code, or are you thinking about performance?

Comment: Turn them around: `"Kentucky": [7777,5555]` and look them up using value search

Comment: You can use array as a key in object.

Comment: why dont use filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use array which elements are $mapCodes's keys:

```
{
  "Idaho":[1991,1282]
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
$mapCodes = {
  "Idaho":['1991','1282'],
  "Kentucky":['5555','7777']
}
var test="1991 7777 1282";  /// input string
var region = test; // result string
for(let key in $mapCodes){
  let a =$mapCodes[key];
  for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    region = region.replace(a[i],key);
  }
}
console.log(region);
```

Comment: This work perfectly indeed. Thanks you all and apologise for my mistakes in the post, is my first time :D

Answer (score 0):

imudin07 already answered correctly and with easier-to-read code, but just out of curiosity, here's another possibility, using modern JS syntax and array methods [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var mapCodes = {
  "Idaho": ['1991', '1282'],
  "Kentucky": ['5555', '7777']
};
var input = "1991 7777 1282 9999";
var result = input.split(' ').map((inputCode) => (
  Object.keys(mapCodes).reduce((matchingState, curState) => (
    matchingState || (mapCodes[curState].some((code) => code === inputCode) ? curState : false)
  ), false) || inputCode
)).join(' ');
console.log(result);
```